# Cron job not running in AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, aws-opsworks

I have created a task that runs perfectly in my local computer when I run `rake mailgun` now I have created a cron task directly in my AWS machine through a crontab file. This is the code I have

```
* * * * * cd /srv/www/texteditor/current && /usr/local/bin/rake mailgun RAILS_ENV=production
```

I do have the extra line break at the end of the file.
I added `* * * * * env > /tmp/env.output` after that line, and that task ran just fine. So I know `cron` is working

I am using Linux based Opswork in AWS.

My rake task is in my `lib/tasks` folder inside a `email.rake` file:

```
task :mailgun => :environment do
    UserMailer.mailgun.deliver
  end
```

If I run `bundle exec rake mailgun` from my app folder in Ubuntu the task works

Some other things I have tried:

```
deploy@rails-app1:/home/ubuntu$ ps -ef | grep cron | grep -v grep
root       991     1  0  2015 ?        00:05:04 cron

deploy@rails-app1:/home/ubuntu$ pgrep cron 
991
```

What can be causing the task not to work?

Comment: Do you have full paths in your script? Check the [debugging crontab section](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info) for the most common issues.

Comment: @fedorqui if I run the commands manually it works, but not when its in the cron. I'm thinking it might have to do with some sort of permission to send emails form cron

Comment: It is difficult to tell. You may want to check cron's logs (in `/var/log/cron`, normally).